# Is there any freelancing site that allows workers from Iran?

Tags: software, translations

Are there any (international/non-iranian) websites that allows Iranians to freelance?
I tried a few but they don't let me register due to US sanctions.

Comment: I just checked and found out that three sites are not allowing to create accounts from Iran. However, there are few other sites like 99designs.com, which do not belong to US and you can create account while being an Iranian

Comment: You can try 99designs.com. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are freelancing sites like **Upwork, Fiverr, Freelancer, PeoplePerHour** on which registration is not specified to any particular country. On these sites, you can freelance from anywhere around the globe. All you need is good skills that are needed by the buyers/clients and services that can attract clients.

However, in your case, as Iran comes under US sanction, you get left with very few sites. One of them is **99designs.com**, and it allows people from **Iran** too.

Comment: Iran, Fiverr, and Freelancer *all* do not permit Iranians or will ban them soon after joining. Each of them (especially Upwork.com, Freelancer.com, and Guru.com) will eventually *force* you to verify your identity in order to be paid.

Comment: @coderpro.net Yes, that's what I have mentioned above!